# A problem on sums of powers

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

For $n \ge 3,$ if
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k^m = y_m = (m+1)n-2, \quad \forall 1 \leqslant m \leqslant n - 1$$
then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k^n = y_n = n^2+n-2.$$
Essentially, $y_1,y_2,y_3 \ldots y_n$ are in arithmetic progression(A.P) whose first term is $2n-2$ and common difference is $n$.

**CASE $n=3$:** We see when $n=3$ that
$$x_1+x_2=4,\quad x_1^2+x_2^2=7.$$
Now, we need to show that $x_1^3+x_2^3=10.$

**Proof:**

We know that
\begin{gather*}
x_1^3+x_2^3=(x_1+x_2)^3-3x_1x_2(x_1+x_2),\\
x_1^3+x_2^3=64-12x_1x_2.\tag{1}
\end{gather*}
Also, we know that
\begin{gather*}
(x_1+x_2)^2-(x_1^2+x_2^2)=2x_1x_2,\\
4^2-7=2x_1x_2,\\
x_1x_2=\frac{9}2.\tag{2}
\end{gather*}
Putting $(2)$ in $(1)$, we see that $x_1^3+x_2^3=10.$ And indeed,
$$\left(\frac{4+i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{4-i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)=4,$$
$$\left(\frac{4+i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{4-i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2=7,$$
$$\left(\frac{4+i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^3+\left(\frac{4-i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^3=10.$$

**CASE $n=4$:**
We see when $n=4$ that
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=6,$$
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=10,$$
$$x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=14.$$
Now, we need to show that $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4=18.$

**Proof:**

We know that

\begin{gather*}
x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2-2(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3),\\
10=36-2(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3),\\
x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3=13,\\
(x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_1x_3)^2=169,\\
x_1^2x_2^2+x_2^2x_3^2+x_1^2x_3^2+2x_1x_2x_3(x_1+x_2+x_3)=169,\\
x_1^2x_2^2+x_2^2x_3^2+x_1^2x_3^2+12x_1x_2x_3=169,\\
\frac{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^2-(x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4)}{2}+12x_1x_2x_3=169.\tag{3}
\end{gather*}

Also, we know that
\begin{align}
x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3-3x_1x_2x_3=(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_1^2+x_2^2+&x_3^2-x_1x_2-x_2x_3-x_1x_3),
\end{align}
we have
\begin{gather*}
14-3x_1x_2x_3=6(10-13),\\
x_1x_2x_3=\frac{32}{3}.\tag{4}
\end{gather*}
Putting $(4)$ into $(3),$ we have
\begin{gather*}
\frac{10^2-(x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4)}{2}+12\left(\frac{32}{3}\right)=169,\\
x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4=18.
\end{gather*}
And indeed, if
$$\alpha=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}3+\frac{2\sqrt{3}}9}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}3-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}9}+2,$$
then

\begin{align}
\alpha+\left(\frac{-3\alpha(\alpha-6)+i\sqrt{384\alpha-(3\alpha(\alpha-6))^2}}{6\alpha}\right)+&\left(\frac{-3\alpha(\alpha-6)-i\sqrt{384\alpha-(3\alpha(\alpha-6))^2}}{6\alpha}\right)=6,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\alpha^2+\left(\frac{-3\alpha(\alpha-6)+i\sqrt{384\alpha-(3\alpha(\alpha-6))^2}}{6\alpha}\right)^2+&\left(\frac{-3\alpha(\alpha-6)-i\sqrt{384\alpha-(3\alpha(\alpha-6))^2}}{6\alpha}\right)^2=10,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\alpha^3+\left(\frac{-3\alpha(\alpha-6)+i\sqrt{384\alpha-(3\alpha(\alpha-6))^2}}{6\alpha}\right)^3+&\left(\frac{-3\alpha(\alpha-6)-i\sqrt{384\alpha-(3\alpha(\alpha-6))^2}}{6\alpha}\right)^3=14,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\alpha^4+\left(\frac{-3\alpha(\alpha-6)+i\sqrt{384\alpha-(3\alpha(\alpha-6))^2}}{6\alpha}\right)^4+&\left(\frac{-3\alpha(\alpha-6)-i\sqrt{384\alpha-(3\alpha(\alpha-6))^2}}{6\alpha}\right)^4=18.
\end{align}

> I have used the same algebraic manipulation used here to confirm that $n=5$ and $n=6$ are also true but the number of steps involved is too long and complicated to post here. Apparently, using the same method for higher cases of $n$ will be unbelievably long and complicated so, i reckon that is not the way to solve the problem.

> **Question:** Is there any method i am not aware of that could solve the problem completely?

For reference purpose, [here](https://vixra.org/abs/2209.0167) is where the full problem proposal is.

Answer (score 1):

Let us work with a fixed $n$. 
This proof makes heavy use of [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials). 
Denote $e_{k}$ to be the $k$'th elementary symmetric polynomial in $n-1$ variables.
Eg. for $n=4$  (ie. with $3$ variables) would have: $$e_0 = 1\\ e_1 = x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}\\
e_2 = x_1x_2 + x_1 x_3 + x_2 x_3 \\
e_3 = x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}$$

The sums of powers, $p_{m=}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k^m$, coincide with our $y_{m}$. We rewrite Newton's identity as:

$$p_{k} = p_{k}e_{0} = (\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{i+1}e_{i}p_{k-i}) + (-1)^{k+1}e_{k}k$$

Since we only have $n-1$ variables, we have $e_{k} = 0 $ for $k \geq n$.  We can recast the identity as:
$$p_k = L(p_{k-1},p_{k-2},\dots p_{1},\;k, 0,\dots,0)$$
where $L: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a linear operator given by: $$L(v_1,v_2,\dots v_{n-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}e_{i}(-1)^{i+1}v_{i}$$
This holds for any positive $k$, even those larger than $n$. 
We've recast the Newton identity as the linear operator given by the dot product with the vector: $(e_1,-e_2,e_3,\dots (-1)^ne_{n-1})$. Our interest now is to find the value of: $$p_{n} = L(p_{n-1},p_{n-2}\dots p_{1})$$
using $p_{m} = (m+1)n-2$ for $1\leq m \leq n-1$ and the smaller degree Newton identities. 
We shall use the Newton identity for $p_{n-1}$ and $p_{n-2}$.

$$p_{n-1} = L(p_{n-2}, p_{n-3}, \dots, p_2, p_1, n-1)\\
p_{n-2}  =  L(p_{n-3}, p_{n-4}, \dots p_1, n-2, 0)$$

By substituting  $p_{m} = (m+1)n-2$ for $1 \leq m \leq  n-1$ we get:

$$p_{n-1} = L((n-1)n-2, (n-2)n-2, \dots, 3n-2, 2n-2, n-1) = n^2 - 2 \\
p_{n-2}  =  L((n-2)n-2, (n-3)n-2, \dots 2n-2, n-2, 0)  = (n-1)n - 2 $$

We are interested in finding:

$$p_{n} = L(n^2-2, (n-1)n-2, \dots 3n-2, 2n-2) $$

Here is the relationship that completes the proof: $p_{k} = 2p_{k-1} - p_{k-2}$ for $3\leq k < n$.  This can be easily checked to hold for our given $p_k$ and allows us to conclude from the above relationships (by linearity of $L$) that: $$p_{n} = 2p_{n-1}-p_{n-2}$$
So the answer we get is: $$y_{n} = p_{n} = 2p_{n-1} - p_{n-1} = 2(n^2-2) - ((n-1)n-2) = n^2 + n -2$$

---

For a concrete example, take $n=4$. We have
$$(p_3,p_2,p_1) = (14,10,6)$$

The Newton identities allow us to conclude:
$$L(6,2,0) = 10\\
L(10,6,3)  = 14$$

Additionally, we have  $L(1,0,0) = 6$, but we are not interested in that. We are interested in $$p_4 = L(14,10,6)$$
We calculate: $p_4 = L(14,10,6) =
 L(20 - 6 , 12 - 2 , 6 - 0) = \\ =  L(20, 12, 6) - L(6,2,0) =
\\ = 2 L(10,6,3)- L(6,2,0) =\\ = 2*14 - 10 = 18 = 4*4 + 4 - 2 $

Comment: I must admit i got lost after **We can recast the identity as:** It's my fault though as that is the limitation of my knowledge on maths so i can't confirm the validity of this solution. I will leave it to other experts to check its validity, after then i will mark it as answered if correct.

Comment: It's just a "clever" way of rewriting the Newton identities (the relationships we have between $p_k$'s and $e_k$'s), as relations of the form $L(v_k) = p_k$  where $L$ is a linear operator made from $e_k$s and $p$ is a specific vector made from $p_k$ s .  It's not really integral to the proof. More of a notational convenience. For all real numbers $v_1, v_2\dots v_{n-1}$ we write 
$L(v_1,v_2,\dots v_{n-1})$  as shorthand for $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}e_{i}(-1)^{i+1}v_{i}$.

Comment: This is a linear operator, in the sense that $L(a_1,a_2,\dots a_{n-1}) + L(b_1,b_2,\dots b_{n-1})   = L(a_1 + b_1 ,a_2 + b_2 ,\dots a_{n-1} + b_{n--1}) $ and $x L(a_1,a_2,\dots a_{n-1}) =   L(x a_1, x a_2,\dots x a_{n-1}) $ . It is a function with exactly $n-1$ real arguments.

Comment: For $n=4$, the $L(10,6,3) = 14$ translates to $10e_1 - 6 e_2 + 3 e_3 = 14$. Expanding to: $10 (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) - 6(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_1 x_3) - 3 x_1 x_2 x_3 = 14$  The specific newton identity applied here is $p_3 = L(p_2,p_1,3)$ where $p_m = x_1^m + x_2 ^m + x_3^m$ ,

Comment: You said **This holds for any $k$, even those larger than $n$.** Does that mean you can, for instance, get $x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6+x_4^6$ if $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4,$ $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_^2,$ $x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3$ and $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4$ are given?

Comment: You have $p_{6} = L(p_5,p_4,p_3,p_2)$ . So when $n = 5$, for $y_{6}$ you need $y_{5}, y_{4}, y_{3}$, and $y_{2}$.   The core relationship is $p_k = L(p_{k-1},p_{k-2},\dots p_{1},\;k, 0,\dots,0)$,

Comment: You can get $p_{m}$ out of $p_{m-1}, p_{m-2}, \dots p_{m-(n-1)}$ and the $L$ operator.

Comment: In principle yes, you can calculate any $p_{k}$ from $p_{1}, p_{2}. \dots p_{n-1}$.  Just the formulas for doing so are not exactly easy. The easiest case would be $n=3$. You know $p_{2} = x_{1}^2 + x_{2}^{2}$. And $p_{1} = x_{1} + x_{2}$. From that you can  calculate  $e_{1} = x_{1}+x_{2}$ and $e_{2} = x_{1}x_{2}$. For that you  $L$ operator explicitly as $L(v_1, v_2) = v_1e_{1}- v_2 e_{2}$. Then you can use $L$ to inductively deduce $p_{k}$ from $p_{k-1}$ and $p_{k-2}$. We have:

$x_{1}^k + x_{2}^k = (x_{1}^{k-1} + x_{2}^{k-1})  (x_1 + x_2) -  (x_{1}^{k-2} + x_{2}^{k-2}) (x_1 x_2)$